# Unable to get data from Postal Pincode API

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, function, api

I have created a wordpress function in functions.php to get pincode details from API URI. I want to get city and state from the API in my form. Here is my wordpress function.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
});
```

```
function get_pincode () {
$pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
$data=file_get_contents('http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/'.$pincode);
$data=json_decode($data);
if(isset($data->PostOffice['0'])){
    $arr['city']=$data->PostOffice['0']->Taluk;
    $arr['state']=$data->PostOffice['0']->State;
    echo json_encode($arr);
}else{
    echo 'no';
}}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_pincode', 'get_pincode' );
```

Here is the form where I am trying to get the values

```
<form class="elementor-form ihs_si_form" method="post" id="register_form" name="BHC - Registered User">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="9297" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="f62431d" />
    <input type="hidden" name="referer_title" value="Register" />

    <input type="hidden" name="queried_id" value="9297" />

    <div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
        <div class="elementor-field-type-tel elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_35e359d elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_35e359d" class="elementor-field-label">Phone Number</label>
            <div id="ihs-country-code" class="ihs-country-code-exis-mob">
                <div class="ihs-country-inp-wrap">
                    <span class=""><input type="text" name="ihs-country-code" value="+91" class="ihs-country-code" required="" placeholder="e.g. +91" aria-invalid="false" readonly="" maxlength="5" /></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input
                size="1"
                type="tel"
                name="form_fields[field_35e359d]"
                id="form-field-field_35e359d"
                class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual ihs-existing-mob-inp-fld"
                placeholder="Phone Number"
                required="required"
                aria-required="true"
                pattern="[0-9()#&amp;+*-=.]+"
                title="Only numbers and phone characters (#, -, *, etc) are accepted."
                style="width: calc(100% - 5rem);"
            />
            <label id="ihs-otp-required" class="ihs-otp-required ihs-otp-hide">
                OTP( required )
                <span class="wrap ihs-otp"><input type="number" id="ihs-mobile-otp" name="ihs-otp" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required ihs-otp-hide" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
            </label>
            <div class="ihs-otp-btn" id="ihs-send-otp-btn">Send OTP</div>
            <div class="ihs-otp-btn ihs-otp-hide" id="ihs-submit-otp-btn">Verify OTP</div>
            <div class="ihs-otp-btn ihs-otp-hide" id="ihs-resend-otp-btn-id">Resend OTP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_8441032 elementor-col-50 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_8441032" class="elementor-field-label">Address line 1</label>
            <input
                size="1"
                type="text"
                name="form_fields[field_8441032]"
                id="form-field-field_8441032"
                class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual"
                placeholder="Address line 1"
                required="required"
                aria-required="true"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_e040cd6 elementor-col-50 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_e040cd6" class="elementor-field-label">Address line 2</label>
            <input
                size="1"
                type="text"
                name="form_fields[field_e040cd6]"
                id="form-field-field_e040cd6"
                class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual"
                placeholder="Address line 2"
                required="required"
                aria-required="true"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-pincode elementor-col-33 elementor-sm-60 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-pincode" class="elementor-field-label">PIN Code</label>
            <input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[pincode]" id="form-field-pincode" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="PIN" required="required" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-city elementor-col-33 elementor-sm-40 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-city" class="elementor-field-label">City</label>
            <input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[city]" id="form-field-city" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="City" required="required" aria-required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-state elementor-col-33 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-state" class="elementor-field-label">State</label>
            <input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[state]" id="form-field-state" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="State" required="required" aria-required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-date elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_c5e80e9 elementor-col-33 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_c5e80e9" class="elementor-field-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="form_fields[field_c5e80e9]"
                id="form-field-field_c5e80e9"
                class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual elementor-date-field flatpickr-input"
                placeholder="Your Date of Birth"
                required="required"
                aria-required="true"
                pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-select elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_517a55b elementor-col-33 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_517a55b" class="elementor-field-label">Gender</label>
            <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper">
                <select name="form_fields[field_517a55b]" id="form-field-field_517a55b" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm" required="required" aria-required="true">
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-select elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_bee9025 elementor-col-33 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_bee9025" class="elementor-field-label">Marital Status</label>
            <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper">
                <select name="form_fields[field_bee9025]" id="form-field-field_bee9025" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm" required="required" aria-required="true">
                    <option value="Single">Single</option>
                    <option value="Married">Married</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-select elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_16a2398 elementor-col-100 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_16a2398" class="elementor-field-label">English Fluency</label>
            <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper">
                <select name="form_fields[field_16a2398]" id="form-field-field_16a2398" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm" required="required" aria-required="true">
                    <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
                    <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                    <option value="Expert">Expert</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_d1250ef elementor-col-60 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_d1250ef" class="elementor-field-label">Church Name</label>
            <input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_d1250ef]" id="form-field-field_d1250ef" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Church Name" required="required" aria-required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-select elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_7850be2 elementor-col-40 elementor-sm-50 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_7850be2" class="elementor-field-label">Role in the Church</label>
            <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper">
                <select name="form_fields[field_7850be2]" id="form-field-field_7850be2" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm" required="required" aria-required="true">
                    <option value="Pastor">Pastor</option>
                    <option value="Elder">Elder</option>
                    <option value="Deacon">Deacon</option>
                    <option value="Youth Leader">Youth Leader</option>
                    <option value="Worship Leader">Worship Leader</option>
                    <option value="Children Minister">Children Minister</option>
                    <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
                    <option value="Bible College Student">Bible College Student</option>
                    <option value="Church Staff">Church Staff</option>
                    <option value="Member">Member</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-type-radio elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_4fa2d07 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-field_4fa2d07" class="elementor-field-label">Do you promise to give us a 1 Page feedback on all the 14 free books you will receive from us?</label>
            <div class="elementor-field-subgroup elementor-subgroup-inline">
                <span class="elementor-field-option">
                    <input type="radio" value="Yes" id="form-field-field_4fa2d07-0" name="form_fields[field_4fa2d07]" required="required" aria-required="true" /> <label for="form-field-field_4fa2d07-0">Yes</label>
                </span>
                <span class="elementor-field-option">
                    <input type="radio" value="No" id="form-field-field_4fa2d07-1" name="form_fields[field_4fa2d07]" required="required" aria-required="true" /> <label for="form-field-field_4fa2d07-1">No</label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-type-submit elementor-col-100 e-form__buttons">
            <button type="submit" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm" id="register_camp_1">
                <span>
                    <span class="elementor-button-icon"> </span>
                    <span class="elementor-button-text">Send</span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery json parsor script

```
<script>
function get_details(){
    
    var pincode=jQuery('#form-field-pincode').val();

    if(pincode==''){
        jQuery('#form-field-city').val('');
        jQuery('#form-field-state').val('');
    }else{
        jQuery.ajax({
            action: 'get_pincode',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:'pincode='+pincode,
            success:function(data){
            console.log('Submission was successful.');

                if(data=='no'){
                    alert('Wrong Pincode');
                    jQuery('#form-field-city').val('');
                    jQuery('#form-field-state').val('');
                }else{
                    var getData=JSON.parse(data);
                    jQuery('#form-field-city').val(getData.city);
                    jQuery('#form-field-state').val(getData.state);
                }
            },
            
             error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data.pincode);
            }
        });
    }
}


jQuery("#form-field-pincode").keyup(function(){
  get_details();
});
</script>
```

Please help me figure out the error.

Thanks

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid I am not sure if I have called the API correctly. In my console i see "An error occurred".

Answer (score 0):

Believe you are using the data submission URL as `action: 'get_pincode'`. Its should be `url: 'get_pincode'`. Make sure the `get_pincode` is a complete & correct url to your method defined in php file.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get_pincode',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'pincode='+pincode,
        success:function(data){
        console.log('Submission was successful.');

            if(data ==='no'){
                alert('Wrong Pincode');
                jQuery('#form-field-city').val('');
                jQuery('#form-field-state').val('');
            }else{
                var getData=JSON.parse(data);
                jQuery('#form-field-city').val(getData.city);
                jQuery('#form-field-state').val(getData.state);
            }
        },
        
         error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data.pincode);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `POSThttps://forthetruth.abny.in/register/get_pincode
[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 2992ms]` 
If  replace with url I see an 404 error
Here is the page where I want to get the results.

Comment: @HarshitSingh Whats your wordpress version? Have you done the set up of wp_enqueue_script & wp_localize_script ?

Comment: Wordpress version 5.7.1. I have done wp_enqueue_script not sure about wp_localize_script

Comment: @HarshitSingh Can you update the wp_enqueue and related php code to the question

Comment: Updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: Lets continue conversation in this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231506/wordpress-ajax

Comment: I can't it says: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.